# Copy all folders from a specific direcory into multiple subdirectories using for loop

Tags: windows, command-line, command, command-prompt

Basically I want to copy everything under Test

```
Test-> Folders 1,2,3,4,5
```

Into every subdirectory of the targeted folder

```
Test2 -> Folder A, B, C
```

Which will effectivly create the following

```
Test2 -> A -> 1,2,3,4,5
Test2 -> B -> 1,2,3,4,5
Test2 -> C -> 1,2,3,4,5
```

This is the code i tried which obviously did not work :)

```
For %%a in ("C:\Users\helix\Desktop\test") do (for %%b in ("C:\Users\helix\Desktop\test2") do xcopy /s /d /e "%%~a" "%%~b")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "source=c:\users\helix\desktop\test"
    set "target=c:\users\helix\desktop\test2"

    for /d %%a in ("%target%\*") do xcopy /s /d /e "%source%\*" "%%~fa"
```

For each folder inside the target, copy the source into the selected folder